# Liaison Delta Script Language

Tags: edi, amazon-ecs, delta

I am trying to understand how the Delta works in terms of scripting. I have understood the documents that can be received such as 830 etc but is there a tutorial that can help in explaining the script language and walk-through in order to do more to analyze the data received. Any documentation would be great.

Comment: This isn't the place for this question.  You'll want to use this: https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/EDI_Softshare/conversations/messages  The Delta mapper is easy - define your source, define your target and then drag/drop.  If you're looking for info regarding Jscript in a map, that's something different.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your comment and yes I was referring to the JScript used in the MAP as mentioned above. Thank You